# How do you provide your certificate path to Watson assistant?

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I need to include my own certificates while watson assistant creates a session. Currently I have added the certificates in certifi and it works, but when deploying my app, I dont think I can go to the deployment server and add certificate. Where can I reference verify = ?

While using requests library, I provide certificates in verify = 'path to certs'

```
from ibm_watson import AssistantV2
conversation = AssistantV2(
    iam_apikey = config.get('bot_configuration').get('bot_api_key'),
    url= config.get('bot_configuration').get('bot_url'),
    version=config.get('bot_configuration').get('version'))
session = conversation.create_session(config.get('bot_configuration').get('assistant_id')).get_result()
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the flow or the requirement. What is the certificate for?

Comment: behind a corporate firewall, so I need to use the corporate issed certificate to access IBM services, else I get Bad handshake error.

Comment: Do you need that cert in all requests or only for the initial connection? You could use the API: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2

Comment: I definitely need that cert for calling iam.cloud.ibm.com (aka watson authentication) and other services too , but I can turn ssl off for those but not for this

Answer (score 0):

The certificate is needed by the requests library. You can pass it in runtime or specify in certifi path